# Can G-d be put in Charem

Tags: halacha-theory, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, nedarim-shevuot, cherem

I came across this article:
[The Time Has Come for God to Reveal the Messiah, Says Jerusalem’s Chief Rabbi](https://www.breakingisraelnews.com/53767/the-time-has-come-for-god-to-reveal-the-messiah-says-jerusalems-chief-rabbi-jewish-world/).

The jist of the article that Chief Rabbi Amar and two other Rabbis announced as a ruling that G-d must bring the Moshiach.

This gave me a thought if these three rabbis declared that Moshiach must come and G-d is must give a response in 30 days and no show then the rabbis give another 30 days and so on. If no show, can these Rabbis decide that G-d should be put in a state of excommunication. As I was taught that if the Bais Din decide it’s Rosh Hashanah then G-d will agree.

Comment: I understand your excitement, but not everything a rabbi (any rabbi) utters becomes a ruling or a Psak Din!

Comment: 1. G-d cannot be put in Cherem as G-d cannot possibly override the Torah! 2. Will they immediately stop davening 3 times a day? I'd like to see that!

Comment: Will yidden be obligated to refuse rainfall, dew, or winds?

Comment: My second comment addresses exactly that. G-d cannot be Muchram by definition of a Cherem. I wonder what were you thinking about?

Comment: How do you excommunicate te presence of the Shechinah?

Comment: Beware of articles that don't bring the original sources. Fake news by *"Dr. Rivkah Lambert Adler is **a Bible and Prophecy Watch reporter** on Breaking Israel News*."

Comment: @Al Berko How can G-d do Netaras Nedarim in regards to pashas Ki Sisa. I hope no one thinks i’m A apikores. It’s just an idea that I thought that would be like to discussed on this forum

Comment: There is a YouTube videos https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lp97a8N7QNg

Comment: 1. Chas Vehalila, I only taked about the lack of logic, not Apikorus. 2. The link - are you serious? Does it look to you like a Psak - a bunch of Chabadnikes crying for the Rabbi/Moshiach to reveal himself?

Comment: If I heard the words correctly  “אנחנו פוסקים” ok I agree that the setting could have been better rather at a farbreghan.

Comment: Oh, give me a break, can't you see the circumstances? If your kid says: "Daddy I command you to..." does he really command? A Psak requires a question, a discussion and a conclusion. And all in written.

Comment: Marginally related, look at Lilopinpin's comment on this question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87713/did-jacob-ever-figure-out-what-the-brothers-did-to-joseph

Comment: @rosends You could mention that explicitly. Don't mix Midrashic interpretations with Halachah. While interpreting we can turn to metaphors and use our wildest imagination. In Halochos we can't, unfortunately.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Based on @rosend, maybe it's worth to ask a different question on the Brothers that sold Yossef and joined G-d etc. It seems to be a better example of a Cherem (?).

Comment: I”ll give way to my learned friends, on this matter.

Comment: Just some wishful thinking from some Lubavitchers @AlBerko

Comment: I’ve given my upvote on this question. Is it based on a fake news article? Possibly. But that doesn’t go against the actual question, if Hashem is obligated to abide by Halachos paskened on Earth, including being put in Cherem. It’s certainly an intriguing question, especially since we know that Hashem *can* be overruled by Beis Din shel Matah (BM 59b), *can* have His Nedarim removed (Midrash the OP cited in the comments), *can* be overruled in terms of the calendar (RH 25a-b), etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one occasion in History where the 10 Tribes Put a Cheirem that Not even Hakadosh Baruch Hu could reveal to Yaakov that Yosef was alive after they had sold him. But i wouldn't advise anyone to do it other than them as they were Great Tzadikim and they were sure Hashem would agree to participate in their Cherem (Ban not to tell Yaakov about Yosef).
Rashi Bereishis 37,33 quoting Midrash Tanchuma:

> ולמה לא גלה לו הקב"ה לפי שהחרימו וקללו את כל מי שיגלה ושתפו להקב"ה עמהם (תנחומא) אבל יצחק היה יודע שהוא חי אמר היאך אגלה והקב"ה אינו רוצה לגלות לו

Comment: Not necessarily did that involve potentially "putting Hashem in cherem," though. Yefeh Toar to Bereishis Rabbah 91:1 says flatly אין הקב"ה חייב בשמירת הסכמתם כל שאינו חפץ.

Comment: It's a nice thought, but this source says that G-d agreed with them on the Cherem. If he disagreed, or decided to disobey, we don't see that he would have been put in Cherem.

Comment: @meir the 10 tribes were great enough to know that Hashem should agree to to their Eiruv that's why the answer says he doesn't advise people less great to try it as it would not work

Comment: @yosefkorn you mean cherem

Comment: @yosefkorn Agreeing to be part of their group of ten (to make the cherem) is different than agreeing to be bound by its decisions.